# IIS Reverse proxy and ARR returns 504 gateway timed out for all POST method requests

Tags: wordpress, iis, post, reverse-proxy, arr

We have a `IIS` reverse proxy and ARR setup for my WordPress application. WordPress website is hosted in LAMP server but all the public requests to the website is being forwarded through `IIS` reverse proxy and URL rewrite configured in another windows server. Basically same setup as given below in the link

https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

But I have a problem now. None of the POST request getting forwarded to WordPress server, all GET request works fine. `IIS` logs shows 504 Gateway timed out.

As a result users are unable to post comments and submit anything.

I have searched in google a lot but no luck :( . If any one has a solution could you please help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, did you solve this problem? I am having the same issue